# Does $\sigma_f=\epsilon\sigma$ when $\vec{P}=\chi_e \vec{E}$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

(I am working in c.g.s)

The electric displacement is defined to be $\vec{D}=\vec{E}+4\pi\vec{P}$.

In an isotropic material we have $\vec{P}=\chi_e \vec{E}$, yielding $\vec{D}=\epsilon \vec{E}$ where $\epsilon=1+4\pi\chi_e$ is constant.

Now, by a simple use of Gauss' law, the jump of the electric field perpendicular to a surface charged with uniform charge density $\sigma$ is $$\vec{E}^\perp_2-\vec{E}^\perp_1=4\pi\sigma$$

. In the same way, from Gauss' law for $\vec{D}$, $$\oint_S \vec{D}\cdot d\vec{A}=4\pi Q_f$$ 
, we get $$\vec{D}^\perp_2-\vec{D}^\perp_1=4\pi\sigma_f$$
. On the other hand, $$\vec{D}^\perp_2-\vec{D}^\perp_1=\epsilon(\vec{E}^\perp_2-\vec{E}^\perp_1)=\epsilon\cdot4\pi\sigma$$. Does this mean that for an isotropic material ($\vec{P}\propto\vec{E}$) we have $\sigma_f=\epsilon\sigma$?

It seems like an obvious result of what I've shown, but I didn't see this relation anywhere so I'm wondering whether it is indeed so.

Answer (score 1):

Going through some problems, I think I understand why I don't see $\sigma_f=\epsilon\sigma$ written anywhere.

It's because in the majority of problems, the dielectric constant is set to be different on each side of the surface in question. So it generaly doesn't make sense to talk about one $\epsilon$.

In other words, in my question I assumed $\vec{D}_i=\epsilon\vec{E}_i$ for both $i\in{1,2}$, which is generally not the case.

$\sigma_f=\epsilon\sigma$ would be true only if $\epsilon_1=\epsilon_2$. However, this is rarely the case in problems regarding dielectrics (otherwise it wouldn't be interesting).

To conclude, it is more true to write $D^\perp _2-D^\perp_1=4\pi\sigma_f$, because this assumes nothing about the materials on both sides of the surface.